# 3D Model streaming via Google Draco

Tags: javascript, compression

I have came across this new Google technology, [Draco](https://github.com/google/draco),  but found that the documentation is very confusing and limited. May not be the right place to post help regarding Draco and 3D model streaming/compressing/decompressing as I find it hard to find resources.

Wondering if Google Draco will help with platforms build from [Unity3D](https://unity3d.com/) or [react-vr](https://facebook.github.io/react-vr/). If so, how to integrate Draco into projects build from the above platform(s)?

Will appreciate any help regarding how to kickstart this draco and tutorial. Thank you!